# Are there any hazardous products that would come from mixing glass cleaner with lubricant?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, safety

Are there any known safety issues if you mix:

- [Mr.Muscle glass cleaner](http://www.scjprofessional.co.uk/File.ashx?id=82727&cid=220)
- [GT85 spray lubricant](http://www.gt85.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Safety_Data_Sheet-GT85_Maintenance_Spray-SDS-19-11-2012.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing compromising safety will happen. Now, these are two completely different cleaning agents based on alcohol/water and organic-fuel respectively. Most likely will turn white  because these substances are immiscible. Therefore, it will not be a good idea to apply a mix for you cleaning tasks.  This will be  specially so  over wood or any rough porous surface likely as they will absorb the substances resulting in unappealing white or smear white spots.  Application over polished metal surfaces will be ok.